# How to write normal sql query in active records form

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

```
$ba = $this->db->query("select * from result, users, exam_title, states, user_zone, detailed_result, answers
            WHERE users.user_id = result.user_id AND exam_title.title_id = result.exam_id AND users.state = states.state_id AND
            users.user_zone = user_zone.user_zone_id AND detailed_result.given_ans_id = answers.ans_id 
            AND detailed_result.ques_id = answers.ques_id AND users.user_id = detailed_result.user_id AND
            result.exam_id = '".$exid."' AND detailed_result.ques_id = '".$qid."' ")
            ->result();
```

How to write the above sql query in codeignitor active records form

i tried with thie below code but it is showing error

```
 $ba = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('result')
            ->where('detailed_result.ques_id', $qid)
            ->where('result.exam_id', $exid)

            ->where('answer.ans_id', 'detailed_result.given_ans_id')

            ->where('users.user_id', 'detailed_result.user_id')

            ->join('users', 'users.user_id = result.user_id', 'left')
            ->join('exam_title', 'exam_title.title_id = result.exam_id', 'left')
            ->join('states', 'users.state = states.state_id', 'left')
            ->join('user_zone', 'users.user_zone = user_zone.user_zone_id', 'left')

            ->join('detailed_result', 'result.exam_id = detailed_result.exam_id', 'left')
            ->join('answers', 'detailed_result.ques_id = answers.ques_id', 'left')
            ->get()
            ->result();
```

Comment: Post error details also

Comment: it is showing "This web page is not available"

Answer (score 0):

use it as bellow and let me know if any error.

```
       $ba = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('result')

        ->join('users', 'users.user_id = result.user_id', 'left')
        ->join('exam_title', 'exam_title.title_id = result.exam_id', 'left')
        ->join('states', 'users.state = states.state_id', 'left')
        ->join('user_zone', 'users.user_zone = user_zone.user_zone_id', 'left')

        ->join('detailed_result', 'result.exam_id = detailed_result.exam_id', 'left')
        ->join('answers', 'detailed_result.ques_id = answers.ques_id', 'left')
         ->where('detailed_result.ques_id', $qid)
        ->where('result.exam_id', $exid)

        ->where('answers.ans_id', 'detailed_result.given_ans_id')

        ->where('users.user_id', 'detailed_result.user_id')

        ->get()
        ->result();
```

Comment: made changes, use it again and share error if any found.

Comment: This web page is not available

ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Comment: @zub, use $this->db->last_query(); and get complete query and run on mysql interface and then if database error then it will be error of query otherwise you need to check whole page of script, it may be php error.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 $ba = $this->db->select('*')
        ->join('users', 'users.user_id = result.user_id', 'left')
        ->join('exam_title', 'exam_title.title_id = result.exam_id', 'left')
        ->join('states', 'users.state = states.state_id', 'left')
        ->join('user_zone', 'users.user_zone = user_zone.user_zone_id', 'left')
        ->join('detailed_result', 'result.exam_id = detailed_result.exam_id', 'left')
        ->join('answers', 'detailed_result.ques_id = answers.ques_id', 'left')

        ->where('detailed_result.ques_id', $qid)
        ->where('result.exam_id', $exid)
        ->where('answer.ans_id', 'detailed_result.given_ans_id')
        ->where('users.user_id', 'detailed_result.user_id')
        ->get('result');
```

And then get result array from query

```
$result = $ba->result_array();
```